# visual code + linux + C#

Tags: c#, linux

Делал проект на windows, так случилось что нужно доделать его на ubuntu. Вопрос такой как в visual code перенести, запустить и доделать проект в данной среде.

Comment: С консольным приложением разобрался, не могу понять как это сделать с windows forms

Comment: Никак, .Net Core не поддерживает WinForms

Comment: а вообще в ubuntu как доделать оное? есть ли IDE  какое нить?

Comment: WinForms думаю что никак, если только в VirtualBox винду не поднять... Подумайте о переносе WinForms в веб, если приложение не использует что то Win специфичное, например Dx....

Comment: Простите обманул, есть такая штука как [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/download), но Enterprise код я бы ей не доверил...

Comment: Смотрите MonoDevelop.

Comment: Ну, если доделать код на чём угодно, можно на финальной стадии перекомпилировать под Visual Studio и отладить.